# Notational Confusion in a definition of Hartshorne about Smooth of relative dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

This the definition from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry of Smooth of relative dimension n

[image: smooth of relative dimension n]

I want to understand what is meant by $\Omega_{X/Y}\times k(x)$.

$\Omega_{X/Y}$ is the sheaf of relative differentials of X over Y which is a quasi-coherent sheaf of modules over $X$ and $k(x)=\frac{\mathcal O_{X,x}}{m_x}$ , which is a field. What is meant by tensoring
 a sheaf with a field?

Comment: $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is an $\mathcal O_X$-module, so you can tensor it with $\mathcal O_{X,x}$. Then both that and $k(x)$ are $O_{X,x}$-modules.

Comment: $\Omega _{X/Y}$ is an sheaf of $\mathcal O_{X}$ module. How do you tensor it with a ring $\mathcal O_{X,x}$?

Comment: Sorry, I think my previous comment was a bit sloppy. I should have said: localise, to get take the stalk $\Omega_x$ of $\Omega_{X/Y}$ at $x$. That is an $\mathcal O_{X,x}$-module. So too is $k(x)$.

Comment: Sometimes people call this the "fibre" of the sheaf at $x$ and write it as $\mathscr{F}|_x$ or $\mathscr{F}(x)$. On the one hand it doesn't quite make sense but on the other hand it means the only thing that it could. I suspect that it's the same data as tensoring with the skyscraper at $x$ with group $k(x)$ but I always mess this sort of thing up.